# How to use wc -l integer output in a if statement

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute the command `git diff | grep pkg/client/clientset | wc -l` and check if the output is more than 0 or not. I have the following script

```sh
if [ "$(git diff | grep pkg/client/clientset | wc -l "$i")" -gt "0" ]; then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

I am getting the following error while executing the script. The error I am getting is

```sh
line 29: [: : integer expression expected
```

Any idea of what can be going wrong?

Comment: What is `$i`? If you give a filename argument to `wc`, it doesn't use the piped stdin.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a trace of the execution.

Comment: @Barmar No it is not a file. I found this in a SO post. Can you please tell me what shall be the command?

Comment: If it's not a file, what is it? Where do you set that variable? Usually a variable named `i` is an iteration variable, e.g. `for i in *.txt`

Comment: What SO post did you get it from? Don't just copy code without understanding how it works.

Comment: @Barmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767122/wc-does-not-return-an-integer-value-integer-expression-expected

Comment: In that question, `$i` is the filename from the loop `for i in */*.$2`. Do you have a similar loop in your script? If not, why are you using `$i`?

Comment: Just get rid of `"$i"` from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- EDIT --

There were some incorrect statements in the answer, pointed-out by commentators Gordon Davisson and iBug. They have been corrected in this version of the answer. The final conclusion (remove the `"$i"`) remains the same though.

`wc -l "$i"` will count the lines in the file `$i`. If you never used `i` as a variable, then `i` will be empty and the command will be `wc -l ""`. The output of that will be empty on STDOUT en contain `wc: invalid zero-length file name` on STDERR. If the variable `i` is used, `wc` will most likely complain about a non-existing file.  The point is, that `wc` will not read STDIN.

I also made some incorrect statements about the quoting. As pointed out, between the `(` and `)`, it is a different quoting context. This can be shown as follows:

```
$ a="$(/usr/bin/echo "hop")"
$ echo $a
hop
$ b=hop
$ a="$(/usr/bin/echo "$b")"
$ echo $a
hop
```

Just removing `"$i"` from the `wc-l` will solve your issue.

```
if [ "$(git diff | grep pkg/client/clientset | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]; then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Comment: `$i` may expand to nothing and no argument, but `"$i"` will expand to an empty argument if the variable is empty. In C that would be a difference in `argc` and an extra `argv[2]` that points to a zero-length string (first byte is zero).

Comment: Except, that the first quote before the `$i` is a closing quote and the second quote after the `$i` is an opening quote. But I see your point.

Comment: @LjmDullaart The original quoting is correct (or would be if `$i` belonged there) -- the inside of `$( )` is a separate quoting context from the outside, so the quotes inside it match each other rather than the ones outside it.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the number of output lines to zero is almost always an antipattern. `diff` and `grep` both already tell you whether there was a difference (exit code 1) or a match (exit code 0) precisely so you can say

```sh
if diff old new; then
   echo "There were differences"
fi

if git diff --exit-code; then
    echo "There were differences"
fi

if git diff --exit-code pkg/client/clientset; then
    echo "There were differences in this specific file"
fi

if git diff | grep -q pkg/client/clientset; then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Notice that `git diff` requires an explicit option to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Only a note, that is to long for a comment:

```
if [ "$(git diff | grep pkg/client/clientset | wc -l "$i")" -gt "0" ]; then
```

I think you will test the existence of string `pkg/client/clientset` to enter the `then` part. In this case you can use:

```
if git diff | grep -q pkg/client/clientset; then
```

`grep` will only returns a status because option `-q`. The status is true after the first occurrence of the string. At this point grep stops. And this status is used by `if`.